# What happens internally when you remove an object from a treemap

Tags: data-structures, search-trees, dictionaries, binary-search-trees

I am wondering what happens if you remove an object in the middle of a treemap. 
If the treemap would look something like this:

[image]

So what would happen if you remove the number 30? Because 27 and 34 will disconnect from the tree.

Comment: Are you talking about the specific implementation in Java ([`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)) or just in general? The short answer is you have to reattach all the disconnected nodes.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't the place to come to for answers from the textbook. If you ask specifically about `java.util.TreeMap`, read about Red-Black trees and study the source code.

Comment: I want to know what happens in java. If it rebuilds it how does it do it? Put everything back in a list or just shuffle everything?

Comment: According to the docs I just linked, it uses the algorithm from CLR; if you want more info, that's where to look.

Comment: [This is what happens internally](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/TreeMap.java#TreeMap.deleteEntry%28java.util.TreeMap.Entry%29).

Comment: @Spotted I have seen that source code and found the method that fixes the tree but I can't figure out what is going on. You can find the sourcecode [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/TreeMap.java#TreeMap.fixAfterDeletion%28java.util.TreeMap.Entry%29)

Comment: Red-black trees are a very well-known, classical technique. The  definitive explanation on how they work, including adding, removing, balancing etc. is in the book [Introduction To Algorithms](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1802051/4125191) by Cormen, Leiserson and Rivest (shortly referred to as CLR). If you want to understand the code, you should familiarize yourself with the technique, the "coloring" of the nodes etc. Most people here don't wish to re-introduce this well-known explanation, so you should go to the source (or try Wikipedia).

Comment: Google "binary search tree".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two cases here

1. **Java Collections implementation** : 
    In this case Java uses red black tree to keep the tree balanced and to maintain the order. Thus if you are removing a node in such a tree it will adjust itself without breaking anything and will form a perfect BST even after removal. Red black trees are self balancing trees so it will also arrange itself to maintain log(n) height where n is the number of nodes. Thus for sure you will not lose any data here.
2. **Your custom implementation** : 
   In this case you have to do all the painful things which I have explained above. However you have an option to maintain the order or to rebalance the tree as per your requirements.